# Set an empty string for function argument with list

Tags: arguments

I have a function argument and want to set an empty string for `name` and `mode`.  What can I do?

```
(defun bench (&optional name mode prefix)
  "DOCSTRING"

  (interactive
   (cond

    ((equal current-prefix-arg nil)
     (list

      current-prefix-arg)))))
```

Comment: Your question doesn’t make any sense. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Want to fill name and mode with empty or default strings.

Comment: `cl-defun` allows you to set defaults for optional arguments.  Do `C-h f cl-defun` to learn more.

Comment: Can I do `(list "" "" current-perfix-arg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t really know what you want, but based on your comment you want the `name` and `mode` variables to be strings if the caller passes in nil or omits them. While `cl-defun` is an option, I wouldn’t do anything fancy at all.

Instead, when you go to use `name` or `mode` in the body of your function, just write `(or name "")` and `(or mode "")` instead. The `or` function looks at each argument in turn and gives you the first one that is non–nil. Like this:

```lisp
(defun bench (&optional name mode prefix)
  "DOCSTRING"
  (message "name=%s mode=%s" (or name "") (or mode ""))
```

If you find yourself in a situation where you need to type these expressions out more than once, just use `let` to rebind them:

```lisp
(defun bench (&optional name mode prefix)
  "DOCSTRING"
  (let ((name (or name ""))
        (mode (or mode "")))
    …))
```

I wouldn’t try to do anything tricky with the `interactive` declaration. Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: In my function I was only doing `(if name` and `(if mode` or `(if (string= "" name)`.

Comment: But I still have to set three values for the list that fills the three function arguments.  Would I use `nil` or `""` when using the function interactively.

Comment: No, you don’t have to. But if you _want_ to use that type of interactive form, you can use whatever values you want in the list.

Comment: If I want to use that type of interactive form, then I have to make the three valued list, right?  If I have optional arguments, can I just fill in just some of them in the interactive list setup?

Comment: With this type of interactive form, you must supply a list of values to be used as arguments. They will be applied to the arguments in precisely the same manner as any other list of arguments. This means that the values are applied to the arguments in order, and you do not have to specify a value for the optional arguments. There is really nothing complex here. Did you try something that failed? If so, you really should include it, and the error you got, in the question. Otherwise people will think you haven’t even bothered to try it.